# Vue CLI 3, My image assets return a 404 error?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

**Hello everyone,**

I'm pretty new to vue. I'm currently trying to code a site using Vue for educational purposes. I'm using this project (https://github.com/ilyasjabar/MyPortfolio), but for some reason the image pathing seems to mess up for all images whenever I build the site.
I'm really lost as to how to fix the image problem, would really appreciate some help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be a great help if you could post the text of any errors or explain more about what you think the issue with paths to the image so that others can help you out. If images are not being found, have you checked to make sure the image is at the location you are trying to load it from?

Comment: Yes, images are in the /src/assets/img directory. everything works except the image return error. Actually its already in place! What I did is just , npm install
,npm run build, and that is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer assets directly using "@" like this:

```
<img src="@/assets/img/moi.jpg"/>
```

In your case: go to `src/components` folder, in Header.vue file refer img like this:

```
<img src="src/assets/img/logo-white.png" class="logo">
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot! But why does work in this way? and what if I had a boolean images?

Comment: What do you mean by boolean images? if you want change img src conditionally you can bind it like `:src=" "`

Comment: I mean array sorry! More than one images in.js file!

Comment: You can create  an array of image's src and bind it like: `imageSrc = ['src1','src2']`